# "Об их" и "о их"

Tags: предлоги, выбор-варианта

Увидел такое предложение: "Это заблуждение, которое говорит только **о их** внутренних комплексах".

Посмотрел на [Грамоте](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BE%D0%B1&all=x#:%7E:text=2.-,%D0%A3%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80.,%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BB%D1%8C%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%83.):

> **ОБ, *предлог*. 1.** Употр. вместо "о" (2.О): перед словами, начинающимися с гласной, например: об армии, об искусстве, об отце, об угол... **2.** Употр. наряду с "о" перед словами, начинающимися с йотированной гласной, перед местоимением "их"...

В этой статье отдельно упоминается "их". С чем это связано? С тем, что буква И находится как бы между йотированными и нейотированными гласными? И поэтому легко читается и с предлогом О, и с предлогом ОБ?

Comment: Наряду с О? Наоборот: в НКРЯ соотношение 3 712 к 781  в пользу предлога ОБ.

Comment: Попробуйте прочитать это предложение вслух. Скорее всего, вам самому оно оцарапает уши, как оцарапало мне. Я не знаток теории, но я бы никогда так не сказал, только "об их комплексах".

Comment: @shampar Скажите, пожалуйста, почему цифры разнятся? Мне выдаёт 2 851 (4094 вхождений) на "об их" и 643 (911 вхождений) на "о их". И всё-таки употребляется "наряду с О".

Comment: @m.vokhm  А мне не режет слух. Вопрос возник потому, что глаз зацепился за О.

Comment: Почему разнятся, знать не могу, но суть одна — О ИХ четверть от числа ОБ ИХ. Но Грамота формулирует именно так, а не иначе. Не запретишь.

Comment: Я бы наоборот никогда не сказал "об их комплексах", уши царапает. Чтобы получить правильную статистику нужно во-первых, чтобы "их" было притяжательным и во-вторых, чтобы следующее слово начиналось с согласной.

Comment: @user190920 Да, "о их" нормально звучит, и мне почему-то кажется, что "об их" какое-то грубое что ли, даже просторечное или устаревающее (но это так, гипотеза). Только я не понял, почему, как Вы пишете, следующее слово должно начинаться с согласной? Чем отличается "о/об их комплексах" от "о/об их окнах"?

Comment: Ну, в первом "их" можно проглотить, или поставить назад, или "не заметить", ведь оно притяжательное. Но во втором все эти приёмы не помогут. Но с другой стороны, они и не требуются, так как окна не соседствуют с о/об. Я сейчас произнес в слух "о их окнах" и, действительно, звучит приятнее. Думаю, что причина еще и в том, что "об" не совсем синоним "о". Например, "удариться об стену" звучит лучше чем удариться о стену. Мы видим, что дифференциация о/об связана с падежами, а не только с гласными/согласными.

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой А почему Вы удалили метки "О" и "ОБ"? Они ведь предлагались, я их и выбрал как самые точные для моего вопроса.

Comment: Понимаете, их до Вас никто не использовал. Лучше выбирать общепринятые метки и не создавать на вопрос о каждом слове метку с ним. Так получится, что меток станет огромное количество.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Второй ответ (дополнительное пояснение  темы)

– Простите, не понимаю, **как связан мой вопрос с наращением Н.** Для общей информации?

– Нет, нет, что вы! Без наращения Н объяснить ваш вопрос **просто не получится.**

1. Если слово начинается **с гласной**, то требуется предлог ОБ, а не О. Почему? Встреча **двух гласных нехарактерна** для русского языка, их желательно разделить **согласным** звуком (например, Б или Н).
2. В словаре говорится: предлог ОБ используется **в м е с т о** О перед **гласной**.

Местоимение ИХ начинается с гласной, значит, можно сказать: ***думаю об их.***
Но это неверно, так не говорят. Почему? Для **личных местоимений** используется согласная  Н: ***думаю о них.*** Значит, п. 1 словаря для личных местоимений неприменим. **Вас это не удивляет?** Получается, что это исключение?

Поэтому в пункте 2 **особо оговаривается вариант с местоимением ИХ.** Там сказано: предлог ОБ используется перед местоимением ИХ **н а р я д у с предлогом О.** Но  касается  это исключительно **притяжательных местоимений** (для них вариант с Н **запрещен**), о чем скромно умалчивается: ***думаю о их деле/об их деле.*** Оба варианта допустимы.

3. **Какое отношение это имеет к вашему вопросу?** Вы как раз спрашивали, почему местоимении ИХ упоминается особо.  Вы сделали такое **предположение**: может быть, гласная И похожа на йотированную гласную?  Нет, дело **не в фонетике.** А в чем дело – я уже объяснила в ответе.

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!

Comment: Поставил вам плюсик, но не нашёл, где говорится, что *предлог ОБ используется перед местоимением ИХ наряду с предлогом О.*

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой  Об этом говорится в цитате из моего вопроса (Грамота.ру, Большой толковый словарь).

Answer (score 4):

1. В данном предложении, где ИХ – притяжательное местоимение, можно использовать **оба предлога** (О и ОБ):

(1) *Это заблуждение, которое говорит только **о их** внутренних комплексах. (2) Это заблуждение, которое говорит только **об их** внутренних комплексах*.

2. **Из словаря:**

**ОБ, предлог** (1) Употр. **вместо** "о" перед словами, начинающимися **с гласной**, например: об армии, об искусстве, об отце, об угол; в отдельных выражениях перед словами, начинающимися с согласной, например: рука об руку, биться как рыба об лёд.  (2) Употр. **наряду** с "о" перед словами, начинающимися с йотированной гласной, перед **местоимением "их"** и иногда в разговорной речи перед словами, начинающимися с согласной, например: об ель, об его занятиях, об их деле, об рояль, об липу.

3. **Почему упомянуто местоимение ИХ?** Здесь дело **не в фонетике** (буква И находится как бы между йотированными и нейотированными гласными, поэтому легко читается и с предлогом О, и с предлогом ОБ), а **в особых правилах для местоимений.**

Если ИХ – это **личное местоимение**, то требуется **обязательное наращение Н** для первообразных предлогов: думаю о них.

Если ИХ – это **притяжательное местоимение**, то **наращение Н не допускается**, и тогда можно использовать **оба предлога**: думаю о их деле / об их деле.

**Примечание.** Правила наращения Н для местоимений можно посмотреть у Розенталя: [§169. Личные местоимения, пункт 5](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/60.htm).

Comment: Большое спасибо! Только, простите, не понимаю, как связан мой вопрос с наращением Н. Для общей информации?

Comment: Спасибо, Роман!

Answer (score 2):

К сожалению, в данном вопросе не найти какой-то значимой логики — такая неопределенность использования *о* и *об* с *их* сложилась исторически и обуславливается относительной новизной местоимения.

Далее использую материалы "Исторической  грамматики  русского  языка"<sup>1</sup> Иванова В.В. Рекомендую к прочтению — очень интересный источник об истории языка.

Личные местоимения для 3-го лица (а тем более притяжательные местоимения 3-го лица) в языке появились сравнительно недавно — значительно позже местоимений 1-го и 2-го лиц.

Падежная форма *их* происходит от формы множественного числа древнего указательного местоимения: **и*, **ꙗ*, **ѥ* (формы именительного падежа реконструированы из сохранившихся падежных форм и составного *иже*, *ꙗже*, *ѥже* см. "Старославянский язык"<sup>2</sup> Хабургаева Г.А.).

В частности, *ихъ* была формой родительного и предложного (тогда *местного*) падежей для всех трех родов.

В то же время, исконные формы некоторых предлогов содержали конечный *-н*: *вън*, *сън*, *кън*.

Употребляя эти предлоги с местоимениями получаем конструкции: *вън ѥмь* (в нем), *сън имь* (с ним), *кън ѥмоу* (к нему). Со временем конечная *-н* предлога переходит в начальную *н-* местоимения и постепенно это начинает относиться ко всем предлогам, что можно увидеть уже в ранних памятниках письменности: *ѹ него то ωтимаеть* (Грамота Мстислава, 1130).

Что касается притяжательных местоимений, то они тоже существовали только для 1-го и 2-го лиц. Когда 3-е лицо обзавелось личными местоимениями, то возникла потребность и в притяжательных местоимениях 3-го лица, которые произошли от родительного падежа: *его*, *её*, *их*.

Именно поэтому притяжательные местоимения для 3-го лица, в отличие от их аналогов для других лиц, "застряли" в родительном падеже и не изменяются. Пользователи языка пытаются восполнить эту нишу уже более пяти веков: *евый*, *еговъ*, *ихний*, *ихниный* и другие вариации встречаются на письме начиная ещё со средневековья<sup>3,4</sup>.

Кроме того, так сложилось, что притяжательные местоимения не приобретают *н-* после предлогов, в отличие от родительного падежа личных: *думал о них*, но *думал о их доме*.

И если для явно йотированных *его* и *её* это не вызывает вопросов, то с *их* всё не так однозначно.

С одной стороны, некоторые считают, что здесь произношение диктует ставить согласную на конце предлога.

С другой стороны, древние тенденции йотировать *а* и *е* в начале слова также распространились и на начальное *и* в некоторых диалектах. Например, старомосковское произношение (существующее и по сей день) характерно йотирует *их* и *им*, произнося их *йих* и *йим* соответственно, что делает использование *об* менее уместным.

Более того, в зависимости от говора, даже в личных местоимениях *н-* может и отсутствовать после предлога (*к ему*, *с ими*, *о их*) и присутствовать без предлога (*сказал нему*), что ещё сильнее осложняет выбор написания, ведь в таких диалектах оба случая использования *их* могут употребляться с *о*.

Таким образом, возможность употребления как *о*, так и *об* перед *их* связана с тем, что написание пытается имитировать произношение, но сама конструкция ещё не пришла (а может и не придёт никогда) к какому-то последовательному, единственно верному варианту использования.

В современной литературе *об их* более популярно, но и *о их* также очень широко распространено как в устной, так и в письменной речи.

---

1. Иванов В.В. Историческая  грамматика  русского  языка:  Учеб. для сту­дентов пед. ин-тов по спец. "Рус. яз. и лит." — 3-е изд., перераб. и  доп., 1990.
2. Хабургаев Г.А. Старославянский язык. Учеб. пособие для студентов пед. ин-та по специальности №2101 "Русский язык и литература", 1974
3. Бархударов С.Г., Богатова Г.А. и другие. Словарь русского языка XI–XVII вв. Выпуск 5 (Е–ЗИНУТИЕ), 1978.
4. Бархударов С.Г., Богатова Г.А. и другие. Словарь русского языка XI–XVII вв. Выпуск 6 (ЗИПУНЪ–ИЯНУАРИЙ), 1979.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ! Мне, конечно, сложно воспринимать все эти исторические изменения и "не наши" знаки, но было интересно.

Answer (score 2):

Нашёл [интересное обсуждение](http://newforum.gramota.ru/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=6310), где небезызвестный slava1947 приводит много примеров из словарей и высказываний известных языковедов с ***о их.***

Comment: Спасибо! Прочитал и еще раз убедился, что обе формы приемлемы: это, как говорится, дело вкуса и привычки. А еще потому, что всё-таки, как мне кажется, буква И "особенная".

Comment: Ну да, дело вкуса и привычки, но не исключаю, что мне может захочется в одном случае так сказать, а в другом по-другому. ;)

Comment: Точно, и у меня так же – как на язык ляжет. Чем дольше думаю **о этом** (!),  тем больше нравится вариант "о их", язык меньше напрягается, а "обых" кажется некрасивым.

Comment: Ну не знаю, *о этом* язык не поворачивается сказать. :)

Comment: Это я по примеру с "о Анне Ахматовой" из обсуждения по ссылке. :)